# Setting up Annotation Processor with Dependencies using Apache Ant

Tags: java, ant, annotation-processing

I have an annotation processor that is depended on other libraries e.g. Guava, Commons. I already set it up with Eclipse and Maven. However, I want to use it with an Apache Ant's build file. So, I created following target:

```
<target name="compile.frontend" depends="compile.main">
    <mkdir dir="${target}target/frontend/classes" />
    <javac encoding="utf-8" destdir="${target}target/frontend/classes" debug="on" nowarn="true" source="1.6" target="1.6" optimize="on" includeantruntime="false">
        <src path="src/application/java"/>
        <classpath>
            <fileset dir="lib">
                <include name="main/*.jar" />
            </fileset>
            <pathelement location="${target}target/main/classes" />
        </classpath>
        <compilerarg line="-processorpath ${basedir}/lib/main/MyProcessor-1.0.jar;${basedir}/lib/main/javapoet-1.7.0.jar;${basedir}/lib/main/guava-17.0.jar;${basedir}/lib/main/commons-lang-2.6.jar"/>
        <compilerarg line="-processor com.me.MyProcessor"/>
        <compilerarg line="-s ${target}target/frontend/classes/"/>
    </javac>
</target>
```

The error I get is the processor-generated class I instantiated is missing, "cannot find symbol".

The dependencies I added with a ";" separated list are the same dependencies I made Eclipse use the processor properly. I suspect from the output folder `<compilerarg line="-s...`, since when I remove a dependency i.e. JavaPoet I get a "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError" of JavaPoet. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was regarding some directory exclusion using `exclude name` under javac lines:

```
<exclude name="**/folder_name/**"/>
```

There is also no need to add  `compilerarg line`s as I did at the original question. Having the libs under classpath is enough.